# ProxyZone Problems with Harnesses after Angular/Material Update from 15 to 16 using nrwl/nx

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx, angular-cdk, zone.js

I updated from Agnular 15 to Angulat 16.

Now a lot of my Unit Tests fail, claiming:

```
Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
```

I found Issues stating that i shouldn't mix `fakeAsync` and `async`, but i have this error in tests that just use `fakeAsync` or no `fakeAsync` as well.

This only happens when i use the cdk [TestbedHarnessEnvironment](https://material.angular.io/cdk/test-harnesses/overview#using-testbedharnessenvironment-and-seleniumwebdriverharnessenvironment).

I found Issues on github stating i should set target to `es2015`, `es2016` or `es2022` which doesn't change anything.

Other Issues stated i should import `zone.js` and `zone.js/testing` in my `test-setup.ts`. This also didn't change anything.

I tried zone.js versions `0.13.0`, `0.13.1`, `0.13.2`, `0.13.3` and `0.14.0`, which all lead to the same error.